# How to create a simple webkit browser in vala?

Tags: webkit, vala, vapi

I have this simple code:

```
using GLib;
using Gtk;
using WebKit;

public class Browser : Window {
private const string URL = "http://mixtape.quadhome.com/6/";

public Browser() {
    this.add(this.create_web_window());

    this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
}

private ScrolledWindow create_web_window() {
    var view = new WebView();
    view.load_uri(Browser.URL);

    var scrolled_window = new ScrolledWindow(null, null);
    scrolled_window.set_policy(PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, PolicyType.AUTOMATIC);
    scrolled_window.add(view);

    return scrolled_window;
}

public static int main(string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);

    var browser = new Browser();
    browser.show_all();

    Gtk.main();

    return 0;
}
}
```

My problem here is when I compile with:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-4.0 searcher.vala
```

It gives this error:

```
fatal error: webkit2/webkit2.h: No such file or directory
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>
```

I use valac-0.26 so it has webkit2gtk-4.0. 
I found with some googleing that there is no "*webkit2gtk-4.0.pc*" so I donwloaded from an arch package and then it wanted "*javascriptcore.pc*" and after I copied that too it gave the same error message. These were all in "*/usr/lib/pkgconfig*".
Now I'm pretty much stuck. Please help me if anyone can.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 2):

first you have to install the dev dependencies..

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev
```

another thing.. in webkit2 theres no need to place the webview in a scrolled window

attach it to the window directly

```
window.add(webview)
```

or

```
mygtkwidget.add(webview)
```

Comment: I installed it otherwise the error would be it doesnt find webkit

Comment: use the vapis of gtk2webkit-3.0 you can find them here https://github.com/rschroll/webkitdom/tree/extension